# Displaying a full "from" name when sending with CFMAIL

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, cfmail

Is it possible to send an email with CFMAIL and have the recipient's email client display the "From" field as a full name (i.e., John Doe or Jane Smith Consulting) rather than just an email address?

The CF11 documentation for the From parameter in CFMAIL says

> This attribute does not have to be a valid Internet address; it can be any text string without white spaces.

And when I tried including a space, only the first word appeared in the From field, at least in Outlook and on an iPhone.

Thanks very much for any advice.

Comment: It should work as well. Just include the code snippet that you have tried in the question.

Comment: Bennadel have explained about cfmail as well on his post; https://www.bennadel.com/blog/689-using-a-name-suffix-in-coldfusion-s-cfmail-tag.htm; Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

Try it like this.  Only the 'Jame Smith Consulting' part will show up for the recipient.

```
<CFMAIL 
FROM="Jane Smith Consulting <info@jsconsulting.com>"
TO="???"
>
```

Comment: I don't think so. The entire string (Jane Smith Consulting <info@jsconsulting.com>) will be there in 'from' according to your code. Hope this post of bennadel helps; https://www.bennadel.com/blog/689-using-a-name-suffix-in-coldfusion-s-cfmail-tag.htm

Comment: I do think so.  That article addresses the problem of when there are commas in a person's name.  But you will see he uses the same method that I am using for display names for normal cases when there are no commas  (refer to his second block of code).

Comment: Sure. Hope you have seen the statement by ben "But, sometimes, when I want to up the level of professionalism,I will add the sender and recipient names to the email addresses:" That means both name and email. According to your code, both name and email will display as from. That what I mention :p According to @rocky, He needs to display only name(full name (i.e., John Doe or Jane Smith Consulting) rather than just an email address).

Comment: My method does exactly what @rocky asks.   Only the name bit will display as the "From" in the recipient's email client.   Naturally, it's a common thing that people would want to do.  This is how CF handles it.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! As you note, I'd think this would be a common requirement, but I don't see it in the documentation. Maybe I'm just missing it.

Comment: Probably because it is not CF specific. (Similar rules apply to most email clients).  [Email address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) *... may have an associated display name for the recipient, which is followed by the address specification surrounded by angled brackets, for example: `John Smith <john.smith@example.org>`*.

Comment: @Justin Megatron Man is correct. Ben Nadel goes into to say "Doing this will use the first value "Ben" as the name to display and will use the value in between the "<" and ">" as the user's email address..." I interpret this to mean that only the name will actually display!

Comment: btw: there is a bug in CF2016 Hotfix 8+9+10 where non 7bit ASCII chars will be converted with punycode and thus not correctly displaying in mailclients: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4204050

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to add sender/recipient names along with the email address.

i.e; For from attribute, the first value "John Doe" as the name to display and will use the value in between the "<" and ">" as the user's email address.

```
<cfmail to="John Doe Consulting<johnconsulting@xxxxxxxxx.com>" 
        from="John Doe<john@xxxxxxxxx.com>"
        subject="Subject">
   Body
</cfmail>
```

But when we try the below code with only name (from attribute) instead of both name and email,

```
<cfmail to="John Doe Consulting<johnconsulting@xxxxxxxxx.com>"
        from="John Doe"
        subject="Subject">
   Body
</cfmail>
```

it will display like below as the email is empty for this case!.

```
John Doe <>
```

Please check [bennadel's post](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/689-using-a-name-suffix-in-coldfusion-s-cfmail-tag.htm) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Put the name in double quotes. Like so:

```
<cfmail to='"John Doe Consulting" <johnconsulting@xxxxxxxxx.com>'
   from='"Jane Doe Consulting" <janeconsulting@xxxxxxxxx.com>'
   subject="Subject">
```